# LINQ select more fields of same type

Tags: c#, linq

For simple example, I have a class like this:

```
public class MyClass {
public string name;
public int item1;
public int item2;
}
```

and a List(MyClass), how do I query the list to create List(int) of both fields item1 and item2? It seems it should be simple but I am struggling a long time.

```
var result = myList.Select(i => i.item1).ToList() //selects only one field
```

I know i could use anonymous type but since both item1 and item2 are integers I dont need any new type.

```
var result = myList.Select(i => new { i.item1, i.item2} ).ToList() //dont need new type, both are integers
```

how to create list of int? Or did I misunderstood what the anonymous types do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't like using anonymous types, you could always use a `Tuple`

```
var result = myList.Select(i => Tuple.Create(i.item1, i.item2) )
```

But since both `item1` and `item2` are integers, you can use an array:

```
var result = myList.Select(i => new[] { i.item1, i.item2 } )
```

This will result in a `IEnumerable<int[]>`. If you want an `IEnumerable<int>` (with each record's `item1` and `item2` together in one result set), use [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var result = myList.SelectMany(i => new[] { i.item1, i.item2 } )
```

Comment: Thanks, i => new[] { i.item1, i.item2 } solves it. As you were 1st I accept your answer as the correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a flattened list you can do:

```
List<int> ints = myList.SelectMany(i => new[] { i.item1, i.item2 }).ToList();
```

if you want to keep the values together you can create a tuple:

```
List<Tuple<int, int>> pairs = myList.Select(i => Tuple.Create(i.item1, i.item)).ToList():
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following expression for example to create a list containing both items fro all elements of the original list `myList`.

```
var result = myList.Select(i => item1).Concat(myList.Select(i => i.item2));
```